# If $\langle\xi\rangle=(1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac 12}$, is the inverse fourier transform of $\frac{\langle\xi\rangle^{-n}}{1+\log{\langle\xi\rangle}}$ bounded?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

> Let $\langle\xi\rangle=(1+|\xi|^2)^{\frac 12}$. Is $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\frac{\langle\xi\rangle^{-n}}{1+\log{\langle\xi\rangle}})$ a bounded function? $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ denotes the inverse Fourier transform.

My idea was to construct some case of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but what I managed is only the upper bound. Any idea or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I changed $<\xi>$ to $\langle\xi\rangle$.  That is standard usage.