# What are the meanings of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ operator

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, poisson-process

I used to know that $\langle a,b\rangle$ is an inner product of two vectors $a$ and $b$. But recently in a research paper I found that during solution of birth death model of a Markov random process, it is written that,
The rate equation of markov random process is

$$ \frac {dP_N}{dN}=\mu(N+1)P_N+1 -[(\lambda + \mu)N+v]P_N +[\lambda(N-1)+v]P_N-1) \ $$

partial differential equation for the moment generating function

$$ Q(z,t)=\langle(1-z)^N\rangle=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty (1-z)^N. P_N(t)\ $$
may be deduced from the first rate equation,
$$ \frac {\delta Q}{\delta t}=z[-\mu +\lambda(1-z)]\frac{Q}{z}-vzQ , $$

i) 
Here, I can not understand what this symbols actually meaning? can <> symbol may be used to find statistical average also??
ii) How this derivation can be done??

Comment: In addition to the answer, be aware that there are other meanings in other contexts ([example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249643/if-langle-xi-rangle-1-xi2-frac-12-is-the-inverse-fourier-transform))

Answer (score 0):

It means expectation according to [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExpectationValue.html).

Notice that it only takes in one input $\langle \cdot \rangle$.